# Conda install opens unwanted files

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I have a conda environment called "gam", whenever I try to install a module, I can install the module but it automatically opens the following files:

```
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam/etc/conda/activate.d/activate_clang_osx-64.sh
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam/etc/conda/activate.d/activate_clangxx_osx-64.sh
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate_clang_osx-64.sh
~/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam/etc/conda/deactivate.d/deactivate_clangxx_osx-64.sh
```

Command:

```
conda install -n gam -c conda-forge nbformat
```

## Question

How to stop automatically opening of these files?

Note: The problem is only with "gam" environment, it does not have this problem with other environments.

## Info

platform: Macos catalina

```
$ conda --version
conda 4.8.5
```

`which conda` gives:

```
conda () 
{ 
    if [ "$#" -lt 1 ]; then
        "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA;
    else
        \local cmd="$1";
        shift;
        case "$cmd" in 
            activate | deactivate)
                __conda_activate "$cmd" "$@"
            ;;
            install | update | upgrade | remove | uninstall)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}";
                if [ $t1 = 0 ]; then
                    __conda_reactivate;
                else
                    return $t1;
                fi
            ;;
            *)
                CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH="${PATH}";
                __add_sys_prefix_to_path;
                "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$cmd" "$@";
                \local t1=$?;
                PATH="${CONDA_INTERNAL_OLDPATH}";
                return $t1
            ;;
        esac;
    fi
}
```

Comment: What exactly is meant by "opening of these files"? Running those files at activation and deactivation of the environment is essential to the proper functioning of the `clang` compiler. Also, what shell are you running in, `bash` or `zsh`?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know what the issue is but you could try using

```
conda install -p <full path> -c conda-forge nbformat
```

Comment: This does not work. `conda install -c conda-forge -p /Users/USERNAME/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam seaborn`. Opens 4 files.

Comment: Did not try it on my own i just saw this command in the [documentation](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/install.html). I assume that in your case it would be something like this "~/opt/miniconda3/envs/gam/etc/conda" not sure though

Comment: Try running the following commands. "activate gam" then "which python" the output should be your path

Comment: and i you activate your env already you could simply run "conda install  -c conda-forge nbformat" and it should work.

Comment: Yes, I have done `source activate gam` and `which python` gives correct path. I have been trying different -p PATHS,  only path `xxx/envs/gam` works and opens 4 files, other paths does not even install modules.

Comment: did you try "conda install -c conda-forge nbformat" while gam is activated.

Comment: Yes, all the problems are occurred in gam env.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223057/discussion-between-cforce99-and-milkyway001).